# proper git branch for an Eclipse Android codebase

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I have an Android project in Eclipse which I've used git for revision control. The project is built around an sqlite database and I've named the project *com.lsp.rengine*.

I now want to create a second application using a different set of data. I can basically copy the new database over the top of the existing one (in assets/) and things work fine.  I will need to change some icons and layouts however, so thought a simple `git branch` would get me on my merry way.

There are a few show stoppers which are stumping me. For one, I can't install both applications on the same device as they currently share the same *com.lsp.rengine* name. If I refactor the project name to *com.lsp.pengine*, my upstream branch thinks all the shared code has disappeared.

How can I manage Eclipse, the two branches in git, and still have shared codebase (update master codebase, changes are reflected in both branches) and somehow have two separate install locations?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to refactor your code into two separate Android projects with a third library project containing all the shared code.  The TicTacToeMain and TicTacToeLib sample projects should be able to help you get started.

Comment: I have over 100 source files I would need to "import", not just two classes as in the TicTacToeLib example (not including layouts). I did some more digging and apparently Eclipse isn't quite adequate for sharing code between projects. A dismal outline of every method is here: http://blog.blackmoonit.com/2010/12/android-sharing-resources-in-eclipse.html.  Been messing with this for two days and if nothing promising turns up soon I'll just dupe all the code for the second project. Not ideal, but may be the only way.